# Makefile ifeq with Bash commands on OS X

Tags: macos, bash, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to write a Makefile that evaluates results from Bash commands, e.g., `uname`.

**Makefile:**

```
OS1 = $(uname)
OS2 = Darwin

all:
    @echo $(value OS1)

ifeq ($(uname),Darwin)
    @echo "OK"
else
    @echo "Fail"
endif

ifeq ($(OS1),Darwin)
    @echo "OK"
else
    @echo "Fail"
endif

ifeq ($(OS2),Darwin)
    @echo "OK"
else
    @echo "Fail"
endif
```

**Output:**

```
Darwin
Fail
Fail
OK
```

How can I compare the variable `OS1` or the command `$(uname)` to the literal `Darwin` inside an `ifeq`? From what I have read, the second `ifeq` in my Makefile should work, but it doesn't.

I am using GNU Make 3.81 for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0 on OS X 10.9.3.

Answer (score 11):

There are a lot of different questions and answers about Makefiles, variables and shell commands. But as it turns out, looking into the manual is sometimes more reliable than searching Stackoverflow.

First, I didn't know the different ways that variables can be assigned in GNU make:
https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reading-Makefiles

Second, the `shell` function, which is required in this case, only works in combination with the `:=` (immediate) operator:
https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Shell-Function

Thus the correct Makefile looks like this:

```
OS := $(shell uname)

all:
    @echo $(OS)

ifeq ($(shell uname),Darwin)
    @echo "OK"
else
    @echo "Fail"
endif

ifeq ($(OS),Darwin)
    @echo "OK"
else
    @echo "Fail"
endif
```

Comment: Right about `shell` but `OS = $(shell uname)` is fine.